# Handling the buttons from dialogfragment in main activity

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment

I want to handle the newgame button and add players button in my main activity. As you can see I'm defining the view in my warningdialog class (which extends DialogFragment, I tried having a getter and tried calling that but I get nullpointer exception, I tried other methods as well but the app crashed.

Whats the best way of doing this? The reason y I want to do this, is because I have other methods in main activity the I want to call when the button is pressed, so I think handling the dialogbutton from main activity is the best choice.

**Here is my Warningdialog which extends from dialogfragment**

```
public class WarningDialog extends DialogFragment {

public Button mNewGame, mAddPlayersBtn;
private ImageButton mCloseBtn;


/**
 * Method to close the dialog
 */
private View.OnClickListener mBtnListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            dismiss();
    }
};

public WarningDialog() {

}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.DialogTheme);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.newgame_dialog,container,false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mAddPlayersBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnAddPlayers);
    mNewGame = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnNewGame);
    mCloseBtn = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnClose);

    //closing the dialog
    mCloseBtn.setOnClickListener(mBtnListener);

}


public Button getmNewGame() {
    return mNewGame;
}
```

**Main activity method:**

```
    private void warningDialog(){
    final WarningDialog warningDialog = new WarningDialog();
    warningDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"Warning");

    warningDialog.getmNewGame().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is have the DialogFragment call back into a public method in the Activity.

In the DialogFragment, add a new OnClickListener for the new game button:

```
/**
 * Method to start new game
 */
private View.OnClickListener mNewGameBtnListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).doNewGame();
            dismiss();
    }
};
```

Then set this as the click listener for the new game button:

```
 mNewGame = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnNewGame);
 mNewGame.setOnClickListener(mNewGameBtnListener);
```

Then, in the Activity, just define the public method that will be called on click of the DialogFragment button:

```
public void doNewGame() {
    //User chose new game!
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked, but not sure if this is best practice? when thinking about encapsulation.

Comment: If you want to remove the tight coupling so that this DialogFragment can be used with more than one Activity, you can define an interface callback, and make the Activity implement the interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `Activity.onActivityResult` from the DialogFragment, and then based on the request & response codes respond appropriately. I don't think your approach can work, because the buttons need to be initialized in `onCreateView` etc, which your activity won't know about.

```
public class WarningDialog extends DialogFragment {
    public static int RC_WARNING = 100;
    public static int RC_NEW_GAME = 101;
    public static int RC_ADD_PLAYER = 102;

    /**
     * Method to handle clicks in the dialog
     */
    private View.OnClickListener mBtnListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            if (v == mCloseBtn) {
              dismiss();
            } else if (v == mNewGame) {
              getActivity().onActivityResult(RC_WARNING, RC_NEW_GAME, null);
            } else if (v == mAddPlayersBtn) {
              getActivity().onActivityResult(RC_WARNING, RC_ADD_PLAYER, null);
            }
        }
    };
}

// In your activity:
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (request_code == WarningDialog.RC_WARNING) {
        if (resultCode == WarningDialog.RC_NEW_GAME) {
          // new game logic
        } else if (resultCode == WarningDialog.RC_ADD_PLAYER) {
          // add player logic
        }        
    }
}
```

You can also pass additional data using the Intent parameter on `onActivityResult`.

Comment: I made the onActivityResult public, but i'm getting  "onActivityResult(int,int,android.content.intent) has protected access in android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity" error message

Comment: Woops, the pattern above is used for communicating between a DialogFragment and a Fragment. Sorry for the confusion.